# Bash Shell Piping $() vs direct command

Tags: bash, redirect, pipe

Newbie to shell programming.

To run a command and put its output in variable we use:

```
var=$(command)
```

**What's the difference with redirect piping between command and $(command).**

*Works*:

```
command | while read line
do
  echo $line
done
```

*Error*

```
$(command) | while read line
do
  echo $line
done
```

Comment: imagine the $() as a shell where you type something

Answer (score 1):

A [Command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) is executed in a **subshell** and the **output** is then placed in the **original** command.
So, basically you are tying to do this;

```
$(command)        | while read line    # Example
result-of-command | while read line    # Bash reads
```

Read more about **Command Subsitution** [at tldp](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Command_substitution), or [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/what-is-command-substitution-in-a-shell)